# Selenium C# - While running - How should i skip the login if already logged in

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here the login code:

```
public void Valid_login()
{
    Config config = new Config();
    Login_methods login = new Login_methods();
    string log_Messgae = login.Login(config.Username, config.password, config.companyID);
    Assert.AreEqual("Success", log_Messgae);


    if (log_Messgae == "Success")
        Logged_status = "logged";
    else
        Logged_status = "loggedoff";
}
```

Here i used conditional statement but it is not working. When running the below code for each and every testcase the browser is launched and going to login page, even if i´m allready logged in.

```
public void Req_Search()
{
    Config config = new Config();
    Menus menu = new Menus();
    Login_methods login = new Login_methods();
    if (loginpage.Logged_status == "logged")
    {
        string current_Url = Driver.driver.Url;
        if (!current_Url.Contains("requisition/requisition-search"))
            menu.Navigate_Requisition_search();
    }
    else
    {
        login.Initilize_Driver();
        loginpage.Valid_login();
        menu.Navigate_Requisition_search();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When opening the the browser, selenium does not open the browser with your profile and instead opens with a default profile that has zero data about your past uses. You can use the following code to open chrome browser with your profile instead of the default profile

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace SeleniumCore
{
      public class Tests
      {
            static void Main(String[] args)
            {
                  string currentUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
                  
                  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                  options.AddArgument($"user-data-dir={currentUser}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
                  
                  IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                  webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because selenium open your default chrome profile.

```
driver.AddArguments(@"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
driver.AddArguments(@"--profile-directory=*name of your profile*");
```

After it will load this profile cookies.

If you're running on headless, dont know why but selenium seem unable to use profiles.